# Is my job successful if I die after the objectives are complete?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

I completed a job, but decided to keep exploring the dungeon before returning to town. Unfortunately, I then died in that dungeon. I was not sure if the job was still considered completed and if I received the rewards.

Is a job considered successfully completed if you die after the objectives are complete, and do you receive the job rewards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the same situation and yes, the job is considered successfull.

The rewards are in your inventory when the "job complete" pop-up with the choice "Explore or return to town" appears.